# Routes syntax in rails 3 from rails 2 to 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to change the following route syntax so that it's compatible with Rails 3.0

```
map.namespace(:admin, :path_prefix => 'refinery') do |admin|
  admin.resources :dashboard
  admin.disable_upgrade_message 'disable_upgrade_message', :controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'disable_upgrade_message'
end
```

Comment: Okay, so what's the problem? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

I will give it a try. The code is taken from examples of [Fernandez: The Rails 3 Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601661)

```
namespace :refinery, :controller :admins do
  resources :dashboard
  match 'disable_upgrade_message' => 'dashboard#disable_upgrade_message'
end
```

Just one note: Your controller should be named `DashboardsController`, and the routes should then be `resources :dashboards`.